# In R, how to write optim() output to text file from within a function called multiple times

Tags: r, optimization, sink

I am using the optim () within a function that gets repeated calls depending on a certain condition. I would like to store the results of each optim() call onto a text file, along with the parameter values being used.

The following code gives me a text file with the parameter values but does not give the optim output ($par, $values, convergence, messages etc.)

I have tried using print(ans) but the optim() output overwrites existing data in the text file. Putting a "flush.console" after optim() also did not give me any result.

This is part of my code:

```
Q2 <- function(s,hf,cumhf) {
    beta<-c(s[1],s[2],s[3])
    alpha<-s[4]
    sigma<-s[5]
    call1<-call1+1
    cat("Q2 ",call1,"\t",s[1],"\t",s[2],"\t",s[3],"\t ",hf[1,1],"\t ",cumhf[1,1],"\t",alpha,"\t",sigma,"\n",file="dump.txt",append=TRUE)
    #browser()
    sink(file="dump.txt",append=TRUE,type=c("output","message"))
    expq2<-function(par){
        alpha<-par[1]
        sigma<-par[2]
        cat("call from expq2 value sigma = ",sigma,"\n",file="dump.txt",append=TRUE)    
        sum2<-0
        for(i in 1:50){
            sum2<-sum2+expectationlogfrailty(i,beta,alpha,sigma)
        }
        return(sum2)
    }
    ans<-optim(c(alpha,sigma),fn=expq2,gr=NULL,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(-Inf,0),upper=c(Inf,Inf),control=list(maxit=250,fnscale=-1))
    cat("optim function summary ",append=TRUE)
    ans
    est<-ans$par
    s<-c(beta,est)
    return(s)
}
```

The text file should look something like this:

---

Q2  1 -0.5675807     -0.4689595      -0.06068879      0.02349636      7.792965   0   1
call from expq2 value sigma =  1
call from expq2 value sigma =  1
.
.
.
call from expq2 value sigma =  2.133043
call from expq2 value sigma =  2.131043
optim function summary
$par

1.186385e-06 2.132043e+00

$value
[1] -113.9802

$counts
function gradient 
       7        7

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"

---

This is only 1 call to this function. The last 5 lines are giving me trouble, either no output or it overwrites the top 5 lines of the text file. Any ideas on how I could append this output to the text file each time?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck if you open a file connection ahead of time and write to the connection (so that it appends) rather than depending on the append argument to `sink` and `cat`.  As it is now one of the commands may not have written to the file yet (holding the output in a buffer) when the other function opens the same file and you lose the output in the buffer.  Having both write to an open file handle may work better.  You can also look at the `flush` function for a way to make sure that each function has written its output before calling the other.

Also you have `ans` by itself inside the function, but the autoprinting does not happen inside of functions, if you want ans printed then you need to use the `print` function directly.